# Displaying numbers with DOS

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, integer-division, signed-integer

I was tasked to write a program that displays the linear address of my
 program's PSP. I wrote the following:

```
        ORG     256

        mov     dx,Msg
        mov     ah,09h          ;DOS.WriteStringToStandardOutput
        int     21h
        mov     ax,ds
        mov     dx,16
        mul     dx              ; -> Linear address is now in DX:AX

        ???

        mov     ax,4C00h        ;DOS.TerminateWithExitCode
        int     21h
; ------------------------------
Msg:    db      'PSP is at linear address $'
```

I searched the DOS api (using [Ralph Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)) 
and didn't find a single function to output a number! 
Did I miss it, and what can I do?

I want to display the number in `DX:AX` in decimal.

Comment: Also [Assembly, printing ascii number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15621258) for a loop that stores into a buffer before making one int 21h / ah=9 call.

Comment: Also [Displaying Time in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37129794) for a simple 2-digit non-looping version, using quotient and remainder from one `div`.  (And printing with BIOS `int 10h`/`ah=0Eh` instead of DOS, just for variety)

Comment: Related: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) - 32 and 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's true that DOS doesn't offer us a function to output a number directly.
You'll have to first convert the number yourself and then have DOS display it
 using one of the text output functions.

## Displaying the unsigned 16-bit number held in AX

When tackling the problem of converting a number, it helps to see how the
 digits that make up a number relate to each other.
Let's consider the number 65535 and its decomposition:

```
(6 * 10000) + (5 * 1000) + (5 * 100) + (3 * 10) + (5 * 1)
```

### Method 1 : division by decreasing powers of 10

Processing the number going from the left to the right is convenient because it
 allows us to display an individual digit as soon as we've extracted it.

- By dividing the number (65535) by **10000**, we obtain a single digit quotient
  (6) that we can output as a character straight away. We also get a remainder
  (5535) that will become the dividend in the next step.
- By dividing the remainder from the previous step (5535) by **1000**, we obtain
  a single digit quotient (5) that we can output as a character straight away.
  We also get a remainder (535) that will become the dividend in the next step.
- By dividing the remainder from the previous step (535) by **100**, we obtain
  a single digit quotient (5) that we can output as a character straight away.
  We also get a remainder (35) that will become the dividend in the next step.
- By dividing the remainder from the previous step (35) by **10**, we obtain
  a single digit quotient (3) that we can output as a character straight away.
  We also get a remainder (5) that will become the dividend in the next step.
- By dividing the remainder from the previous step (5) by **1**, we obtain
  a single digit quotient (5) that we can output as a character straight away.
  Here the remainder will always be 0. (Avoiding this *silly* division by 1
  requires some extra code)

```
    mov     bx,.List
.a: xor     dx,dx
    div     word ptr [bx]  ; -> AX=[0,9] is Quotient, Remainder DX
    xchg    ax,dx
    add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    push    ax             ;(1)
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     ax             ;(1) AX is next dividend
    add     bx,2
    cmp     bx,.List+10
    jb      .a
    ...
.List:
    dw      10000,1000,100,10,1
```

Although this method will of course produce the correct result, it has a few
drawbacks:

- Consider the smaller number 255 and its decomposition:

  ```
  (0 * 10000) + (0 * 1000) + (2 * 100) + (5 * 10) + (5 * 1)
  ```

  If we were to use the same 5 step process we'd get "00255". Those 2 leading
  zeroes are undesirable and we would have to include extra instructions to get
  rid of them.
- The divider changes with each step. We had to store a list of dividers in
  memory. Dynamically calculating these dividers is possible but introduces a
  lot of extra divisions.
- If we wanted to apply this method to displaying even larger numbers say
  32-bit, and we will want to eventually, the divisions involved would get
  really problematic.

So method 1 is impractical and therefore it is seldom used.

### Method 2 : division by const 10

Processing the number going from the right to the left seems counter-intuitive
 since our goal is to display the leftmost digit first. But as you're about to
find out, it works beautifully.

- By dividing the number (65535) by **10**, we obtain a quotient (6553) that will
  become the dividend in the next step. We also get a remainder (5) that we
  can't output just yet and so we'll have to save in somewhere. The stack is a
  convenient place to do so.
- By dividing the quotient from the previous step (6553) by **10**, we obtain
  a quotient (655) that will become the dividend in the next step. We also get
  a remainder (3) that we can't just yet output and so we'll have to save it
  somewhere. The stack is a convenient place to do so.
- By dividing the quotient from the previous step (655) by **10**, we obtain
  a quotient (65) that will become the dividend in the next step. We also get
  a remainder (5) that we can't just yet output and so we'll have to save it
  somewhere. The stack is a convenient place to do so.
- By dividing the quotient from the previous step (65) by **10**, we obtain
  a quotient (6) that will become the dividend in the next step. We also get
  a remainder (5) that we can't just yet output and so we'll have to save it
  somewhere. The stack is a convenient place to do so.
- By dividing the quotient from the previous step (6) by **10**, we obtain
  a quotient (0) that signals that this was the last division. We also get
  a remainder (6) that we *could* output as a character straight away, *but*
  refraining from doing so turns out to be most effective and so as before we'll
  save it on the stack.

At this point the stack holds our 5 remainders, each being a single digit
 number in the range [0,9]. Since the stack is LIFO (Last In First Out), the
 value that we'll `POP` first is the first digit we want displayed. We use a
 separate loop with 5 `POP`'s to display the complete number. But in practice,
 since we want this routine to be able to also deal with numbers that have
 fewer than 5 digits, we'll count the digits as they arrive and later do that
 many `POP`'s.

```
    mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    xor     cx,cx          ;Reset counter
.a: xor     dx,dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx             ; -> AX is Quotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx             ;(1) Save remainder for now
    inc     cx             ;One more digit
    test    ax,ax          ;Is quotient zero?
    jnz     .a             ;No, use as next dividend
.b: pop     dx             ;(1)
    add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    loop    .b
```

This second method has none of the drawbacks of the first method:

- Because we stop when a quotient becomes zero, there's never any problem 
  with ugly leading zeroes.
- The divider is fixed. That's easy enough.
- It's real simple to apply this method to displaying larger numbers and
  that's precisely what comes next.

---

## Displaying the unsigned 32-bit number held in DX:AX

On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) a cascade of 2 divisions is needed to divide the 32-bit value in
 `DX:AX` by 10.
The 1st division divides the high dividend (extended with 0) yielding a high
 quotient. The 2nd division divides the low dividend (extended with the
 remainder from the 1st division) yielding the low quotient. It's the remainder
 from the 2nd division that we save on the stack.

To check if the dword in `DX:AX` is zero, I've `OR`-ed both halves in a scratch
 register.

Instead of counting the digits, requiring a register, I chose to put a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)
 on the stack. Because this sentinel gets a value (10) that no digit can ever
 have ([0,9]), it nicely allows to determine when the display loop has to stop.

Other than that this snippet is similar to method 2 above.

```
    mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    push    bx             ;Sentinel
.a: mov     cx,ax          ;Temporarily store LowDividend in CX
    mov     ax,dx          ;First divide the HighDividend
    xor     dx,dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx             ; -> AX is HighQuotient, Remainder is re-used
    xchg    ax,cx          ;Temporarily move it to CX restoring LowDividend
    div     bx             ; -> AX is LowQuotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx             ;(1) Save remainder for now
    mov     dx,cx          ;Build true 32-bit quotient in DX:AX
    or      cx,ax          ;Is the true 32-bit quotient zero?
    jnz     .a             ;No, use as next dividend
    pop     dx             ;(1a) First pop (Is digit for sure)
.b: add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     dx             ;(1b) All remaining pops
    cmp     dx,bx          ;Was it the sentinel?
    jb      .b             ;Not yet
```

---

## Displaying the signed 32-bit number held in DX:AX

The procedure is as follows:

First find out if the signed number is negative by testing the sign bit.
If it is, then negate the number and output a "-" character but beware to not
 destroy the number in `DX:AX` in the process.

The rest of the snippet is the same as for an unsigned number.

```
    test    dx,dx          ;Sign bit is bit 15 of high word
    jns     .a             ;It's a positive number
    neg     dx             ;\
    neg     ax             ; | Negate DX:AX
    sbb     dx,0           ;/
    push    ax dx          ;(1)
    mov     dl,"-"
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     dx ax          ;(1)
.a: mov     bx,10          ;CONST
    push    bx             ;Sentinel
.b: mov     cx,ax          ;Temporarily store LowDividend in CX
    mov     ax,dx          ;First divide the HighDividend
    xor     dx,dx          ;Setup for division DX:AX / BX
    div     bx             ; -> AX is HighQuotient, Remainder is re-used
    xchg    ax,cx          ;Temporarily move it to CX restoring LowDividend
    div     bx             ; -> AX is LowQuotient, Remainder DX=[0,9]
    push    dx             ;(2) Save remainder for now
    mov     dx,cx          ;Build true 32-bit quotient in DX:AX
    or      cx,ax          ;Is the true 32-bit quotient zero?
    jnz     .b             ;No, use as next dividend
    pop     dx             ;(2a) First pop (Is digit for sure)
.c: add     dl,"0"         ;Turn into character [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
    mov     ah,02h         ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h            ; -> AL
    pop     dx             ;(2b) All remaining pops
    cmp     dx,bx          ;Was it the sentinel?
    jb      .c             ;Not yet
```

---

## Will I need separate routines for different number sizes?

In a program where you need to display on occasion `AL`, `AX`, or `DX:AX`, you could
 just include the 32-bit version and use next little [wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) for the smaller
 sizes:

```
; IN (al) OUT ()
DisplaySignedNumber8:
    push    ax
    cbw                    ;Promote AL to AX
    call    DisplaySignedNumber16
    pop     ax
    ret
; -------------------------
; IN (ax) OUT ()
DisplaySignedNumber16:
    push    dx
    cwd                    ;Promote AX to DX:AX
    call    DisplaySignedNumber32
    pop     dx
    ret
; -------------------------
; IN (dx:ax) OUT ()
DisplaySignedNumber32:
    push    ax bx cx dx
    ...
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind the clobbering of the `AX` and `DX` registers use
this fall-through solution:

```
; IN (al) OUT () MOD (ax,dx)
DisplaySignedNumber8:
    cbw
; ---   ---   ---   ---   -
; IN (ax) OUT () MOD (ax,dx)
DisplaySignedNumber16:
    cwd
; ---   ---   ---   ---   -
; IN (dx:ax) OUT () MOD (ax,dx)
DisplaySignedNumber32:
    push    bx cx
    ...
```

Comment: You could tighten up the decreasing-powers-of-10 version by delaying the `xchg` (and only using `mov` for speed instead of code-size).  `div` / `push dx` / `add al,'0'` (short encoding) / `mov dl, al` / `mov ah, 2`.  Or you could take advantage of the fact that the quotient leaves `ah` zero to `add ax, '0' + (2<<8)` / `mov dx, ax` to leave ah=2 and dl=ASCII_quotient, but that comes at the expense of readability so it's not good for beginners.

Comment: Updated the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) with a link to this from the multi-digit string FAQ entry.  Thanks for writing up a nice canonical Q&A.